# Paypal is not coming in the list of "shoppingCartPaymentList" method of soap api

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2, web-services

```
I am using quote id of 324.
 $proxy = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/stylefiesta/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('karishma.sharma', 'admin123');
 $result = $proxy->shoppingCartPaymentList($sessionId, 324);
```

I am not getting following array in response
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => cashondelivery
            [title] => Cash On Delivery
            [cc_types] => 
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => banktransfer
        [title] => Bank Transfer Payment
        [cc_types] => 
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => checkmo
        [title] => Cash Payment
        [cc_types] => 
    )

)
```

But I am not getting paypal in the list although it is enabled in website.